# Using python's dbus module, is it possible to update the contents of a notification without it poping up again?

Tags: python-3.x, dbus

As a learning project I'm trying to make a simple timer application started from the command line and using desktop notifications to show the count down.  The problem is, when I try to update the contents of the desktop notifications in pops a new notification on the desktop every second.  I need to update the contents of the notice but with it poping up.

Here's the relevant code:

```
def notify_low(self, title, message, update = 0):
    """Pushes a low priority d-bus notice, good for display current countdown"""
    return self.notify_intf.Notify("", 0, "checkmark", title, message, [], {"urgency": 0}, 3000)

def start(self, time_d):
    """Starts the actual timer"""
    self.time_s = time_d.total_seconds()

    self.notice_ID = self.notify_low("Countdown", str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=self.time_s)))

    while self.time_s > 0:
        time.sleep(1)
        self.time_s -= 1
        self.notify_low("Countdown", str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=self.time_s)), self.notice_ID)
    self.notify_low("Bing bong", "Times up!")
```

If anyone knows how to suppress notification pop-ups or how to update without the pop-up it would be a big help.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation at: https://developer.gnome.org/notification-spec/

The second argument of the `Notify` method is `replaces_id`. In your example you have this set to zero and the documentation states that a value of zero means that you will get the behaviour of a new pop-up rather than the existing one being updated. If you replace that number with any value between 1 and 4294967295 then I would expect it to work as you want.

> **replaces_id**   *UINT32*    The optional notification ID that this notification
> replaces. The server must atomically (ie with no flicker or other
> visual cues) replace the given notification with this one. This allows
> clients to effectively modify the notification while it's active. A
> value of value of 0 means that this notification won't replace any
> existing notifications.